# Magento 2.2.x Multistore Full Page Cache Issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

If a Url is opened on a non-default store, same url do not returned from cache in different browser or even in Incognito mode.

Steps to reproduce

```
1.Created 2 different store, Store A, Store B (Default store)
2.Enabled full page cache with In-Built Mode.(Using Redis)
3.Open home page on Store A.
4.Open same home page on Store A in different browser or in incognito mode.
```

Expected result

Home page on Store A, should be rendered from FPC in different browser as it was cached in other browser
Actual result

Page do not return from FPC causing multiple keys in redis.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: No I did not get any response yet even from Magento